# Facebook share to refer back traffic to the iframe page tab

Tags: facebook, url, share

SO here's what I am after. I have a FB page tab that runs the content of the site ***https://site.com/***

I set up a FB share link to share a page ***aboutus.html***. When I share it FB allows me to share this URL ***https://site.com/aboutus.html***, but how can i send the traffic directly to the iFrame on the page tab? For example https://www.facebook.com/fan_page/app_331267943480920398/whatever_aboutus.html

I know it is possible because I saw it one day - cant remember now where.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass in filenames this way, that's only supported on Canvas Apps.

The best workaround to replicate this is using the `app_data` parameter. Basically, have your landing page (as defined in your app settings), be some kind of server side script which listens to the [Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/), specifically the app_data parameter. Then you have that script load content based on the contents of that.

So as an example, let's imagine I want to load **http://mybasedomain.com/foo.php** or **http://mybasedomain.com/bar.php**. I direct users to **https://www.facebook.com/*PAGENAME*/app_*APPID*?app_data=*foo*** or **https://www.facebook.com/*PAGENAME*/app_*APPID*?app_data=*bar***, then on my landing page, I have a simple `if/else` statement to parse that and render the relevant content -

```
<?php

// Assumes you have this parse_signed_request function - https://gist.github.com/872837
// And a $config array, which contains your app_secret

$signed_request = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $config['AppSecret']);

if ($signed_request['app_data'] === 'foo') {
    include('foo.html');
} else if ($signed_request['app_data'] === 'bar') {
    include('bar.html');
} else {
    include('index.html');
}
```